# The UID's in Firebase Authentication and Firebase Realtime Database are different

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I created a login page that asks the user to enter their phone number. After the user enters their number it takes them to a screen where the user types the OTP code send to their phone. After user enters the correct OTP code it sends them to the main screen of my app. But I have one problem. Whenever a new user is added it has different UID in database. It is not the same on as in my Firebase Authentication.

For example I logged in with my own phone number and on my Realtime database my UID is EbC9e1K39MYNJ49M7QrvV8ZLshJ3 and in my Firebase Authentication my UID thats on my phonenumber is R3ZjGJl56vcmwRKLBiUpB0g2xDc2.

Here are my codes:

**CreateNewAccount class**

```
class CreateNewAccount : AppCompatActivity() {
    val mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    var phoneNumber: String? = null
    var username: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_new_account)

        username = accountName.text.toString()

        sendCode.setOnClickListener {
            username = accountName.text.toString()
            val phoneNumberAsText = telephoneNumber.text.toString()
            phoneNumber = "+389$phoneNumberAsText"

            // val numberWithZeroRemoved =  phoneNumber!!.substring(1,phoneNumber!!.length-1)
            progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
                .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber!!)       // Phone number to verify
                .setTimeout(30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
                .setActivity(this)                  // Activity (for callback binding)
                .setCallbacks(callbacks)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                .build()
            PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)

        }
    }

    private fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Auth success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    sendToMain()
                } else {
                    // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure: ${task.exception.toString()}")
                    if (task.exception is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                        // The verification code entered was invalid
                    }
                    // Update UI
                }
                progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
    }

    private fun sendToMain() {
       // startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
    }

    private val callbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {

            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
        }

        override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {


            if (e is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                Log.d("TAG", "OnVerificationFailed:,${e.toString()}")
            } else if (e is FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                Log.d("TAG", "OnVerificationFailed:,${e.toString()}")
            }
            progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            // Show a message and update the UI
        }

        override fun onCodeSent(
            verificationId: String,
            token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken
        ) {

            Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:$verificationId")

            // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
            val intent = Intent(this@CreateNewAccount, VerifyAccount::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("OTP", verificationId)
            intent.putExtra("resendToken", token)
            intent.putExtra("phoneNumber", phoneNumber)
            intent.putExtra("username", username)
            startActivity(intent)
            progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

        }
    }

    fun hideKeyboard(view: View) {
        val inputMethodManager =
            getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }


}
```

**VerifyAccount class**

```
class VerifyAccount : AppCompatActivity() {

    val mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    private lateinit var OTP: String
    private lateinit var resendToken: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken
    private lateinit var phoneNumber: String
    private lateinit var userName:String


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_verify_account)
        resendCode.isEnabled = false
        val timer = object : CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                val secs = millisUntilFinished / 1000
                resendCode.text = "Wait $secs secs"
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                resendCode.text = "Resend Code"
                resendCode.isEnabled = true

            }
        }
        timer.start()

        if (resendCode.isEnabled){
            resendCode.setOnClickListener {
                resendVerificationCode()
            }
        }


        OTP = intent.getStringExtra("OTP").toString()
        resendToken = intent.getParcelableExtra("resendToken")!!
        phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra("phoneNumber").toString()
        userName = intent.getStringExtra("username").toString()

        digitOne.setOnClickListener {
            if (firstDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                firstDigit.text = "1"

            } else if (secondDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                secondDigit.text = "1"


            } else if (thirdDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                thirdDigit.text = "1"


            } else if (fourthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                fourthDigit.text = "1"


            } else if (fifthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                fifthDigit.text = "1"

            } else if (sixthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                sixthDigit.text = "1"
            }


        }
        digitTwo.setOnClickListener {
            if (firstDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                firstDigit.text = "2"

            } else if (secondDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                secondDigit.text = "2"


            } else if (thirdDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                thirdDigit.text = "2"


            } else if (fourthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                fourthDigit.text = "2"


            } else if (fifthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                fifthDigit.text = "2"
            } else if (sixthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                sixthDigit.text = "2"
            }
        }
        digitThree.setOnClickListener {
            if (firstDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                firstDigit.text = "3"


            } else if (secondDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                secondDigit.text = "3"


            } else if (thirdDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                thirdDigit.text = "3"


            } else if (fourthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                fourthDigit.text = "3"


            } else if (fifthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                fifthDigit.text = "3"

            } else if (sixthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                sixthDigit.text = "3"

            }
        }
        digitFour.setOnClickListener {
            if (firstDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                firstDigit.text = "4"


            } else if (secondDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                secondDigit.text = "4"

            } else if (thirdDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                thirdDigit.text = "4"

            } else if (fourthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                fourthDigit.text = "4"


            } else if (fifthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                fifthDigit.text = "4"

            } else if (sixthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                sixthDigit.text = "4"
            }
        }
        digitFive.setOnClickListener {
            if (firstDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                firstDigit.text = "5"


            } else if (secondDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                secondDigit.text = "5"


            } else if (thirdDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                thirdDigit.text = "5"

            } else if (fourthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                fourthDigit.text = "5"


            } else if (fifthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                fifthDigit.text = "5"

            } else if (sixthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                sixthDigit.text = "5"

            }
        }
        digitSix.setOnClickListener {
            if (firstDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                firstDigit.text = "6"

            } else if (secondDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                secondDigit.text = "6"


            } else if (thirdDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                thirdDigit.text = "6"


            } else if (fourthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                fourthDigit.text = "6"


            } else if (fifthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                fifthDigit.text = "6"

            } else if (sixthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                sixthDigit.text = "6"

            }
        }
        digitSeven.setOnClickListener {
            if (firstDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                firstDigit.text = "7"


            } else if (secondDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                secondDigit.text = "7"

            } else if (thirdDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                thirdDigit.text = "7"

            } else if (fourthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                fourthDigit.text = "7"

            } else if (fifthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                fifthDigit.text = "7"

            } else if (sixthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                sixthDigit.text = "7"
            }
        }
        digitEight.setOnClickListener {
            if (firstDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                firstDigit.text = "8"


            } else if (secondDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                secondDigit.text = "8"


            } else if (thirdDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                thirdDigit.text = "8"


            } else if (fourthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                fourthDigit.text = "8"


            } else if (fifthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                fifthDigit.text = "8"


            } else if (sixthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                sixthDigit.text = "8"


            }
        }
        digitNine.setOnClickListener {
            if (firstDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                firstDigit.text = "9"


            } else if (secondDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                secondDigit.text = "9"

            } else if (thirdDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                thirdDigit.text = "9"

            } else if (fourthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                fourthDigit.text = "9"

            } else if (fifthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                fifthDigit.text = "9"

            } else if (sixthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                sixthDigit.text = "9"

            }
        }
        digitZero.setOnClickListener {
            if (firstDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                firstDigit.text = "0"


            } else if (secondDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                secondDigit.text = "0"
            } else if (thirdDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                thirdDigit.text = "0"
            } else if (fourthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                fourthDigit.text = "0"
            } else if (fifthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                fifthDigit.text = "0"
            } else if (sixthDigit.text.isEmpty()) {
                sixthDigit.text = "0"
            }
        }



        clearBTN.setOnClickListener {
            firstDigit.text = ""
            secondDigit.text = ""
            thirdDigit.text = ""
            fourthDigit.text = ""
            fifthDigit.text = ""
            sixthDigit.text = ""
        }

        verifyBTN.setOnClickListener {


            val first = firstDigit.text.toString()
            val second = secondDigit.text.toString()
            val third = thirdDigit.text.toString()
            val fourth = fourthDigit.text.toString()
            val fifth = fifthDigit.text.toString()
            val sixth = sixthDigit.text.toString()


            val typedOTP = first + second + third + fourth + fifth + sixth

            Log.d("typed otp is ", typedOTP)

            if (typedOTP.isNotEmpty()) {
                if (typedOTP.length == 6) {
                    val credential: PhoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
                        OTP, typedOTP
                    )
                    progressbarverify.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter Correct OTP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter OTP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        }
    }

    private fun resendVerificationCode() {
        val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
            .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)       // Phone number to verify
            .setTimeout(30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
            .setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
            .setCallbacks(callbacks)
            .setForceResendingToken(resendToken)// OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            .build()
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
    }

    private val callbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
            // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
            // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
            //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
            // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
            //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without
            //     user action.
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
        }

        override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {
            // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
            // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.

            if (e is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                // Invalid request
                Log.d("TAG", "onVerificationFailed: ${e.toString()}")
            } else if (e is FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                Log.d("TAG", "onVerificationFailed: ${e.toString()}")
            }
            progressbarverify.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            // Show a message and update the UI
        }

        override fun onCodeSent(
            verificationId: String,
            token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken
        ) {
            // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
            // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
            // by combining the code with a verification ID.
            // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
            OTP = verificationId
            resendToken = token
        }
    }

    private fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
        val uid =  FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid ?: ""
        val currentuid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Authenticate Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    val addUserToDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/$currentuid/")
                    val user = User(currentuid,userName,phoneNumber)
                    addUserToDatabase.setValue(user)
                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                            Log.d("Database success","user added successfully")
                            sendToHobbies()

                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener {
                            Log.d("Database failure","user could not be added")
                        }

                } else {
                    // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                    Log.d("TAG", "signInWithPhoneAuthCredential: ${task.exception.toString()}")
                    if (task.exception is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                        // The verification code entered was invalid
                    }
                    // Update UI
                }
                progressbarverify.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
    }

    private fun sendToHobbies() {
        startActivity(Intent(this, Hobbies::class.java))
    }
}
@Parcelize
class User(val currentuid:String,val name:String,val phonenumber:String):Parcelable{
    constructor(): this("","","")
}
```

If someone can help me fix this problem I would really appreciate it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Going forward, consider isolating the problem before asking for help. Following the guidance in [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) increases the chances that someone can help quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found an alternative solution. And that was instead of adding the new user to my Firebase Realtime Database when I verify the user, I take users user name and phone number and pass it to a class called Hobbies(which is the next activity after VerifyAccount)

**VerifyAccount**

```
    private fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {

        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Authenticate Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    sendToHobbies()

                } else {
                    // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                    Log.d("TAG", "signInWithPhoneAuthCredential: ${task.exception.toString()}")
                    if (task.exception is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                        // The verification code entered was invalid
                    }
                    // Update UI
                }
                progressbarverify.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
    }

private fun sendToHobbies() {
        val intent = Intent(this, Hobbies::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("phoneNumber", phoneNumber)
        intent.putExtra("username", userName)
        startActivity(intent)

    }
```

**HobbiesClass**

```
  private lateinit var userName:String
  private lateinit var phoneNumber:String

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hobbies)

        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()

        phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra("phoneNumber").toString()
        userName = intent.getStringExtra("username").toString()

  letsgobtn.setOnClickListener {
            var hobbies = selectedItems.toString()
            val currentuid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
            val addUserToDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/$currentuid/")
            val user = User(currentuid,userName,phoneNumber,hobbies)
            addUserToDatabase.setValue(user)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    Log.d("Database success","user added successfully")

                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    Log.d("Database failure","user could not be added")
                }

            Toast.makeText(this,"Selected item is ${selectedItems.toString()}",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```

I hope it helps others in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

In `signInWithPhoneAuthCredential` you do:

```
val uid =  FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid ?: ""
val currentuid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
            Toast.makeText(this, "Authenticate Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val addUserToDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/$currentuid/")
            val user = User(currentuid,userName,phoneNumber)
            addUserToDatabase.setValue(user)
            ...
```

So you determine the value of `currentuid` **before** you sign in the new user, and then use that value to write the profile of the *new* user.

To write the data under the new user's UID, move the assignment of `currentuid` into the `if (task.isSuccessful) {` block.

Comment: What I did instead of adding the user when I press the verify button. I send my username and phone number informations to the new intent that's called Hobbies. There when I press let's go button I create the new user. It works fine like that. It does not work when I verify(authenticate new user) and add new user to firebase database. Anyways thanks for help!

Comment: I'm confused how that related to my answer. If you found the problem yourself and it was different from what I pointed out, the best thing to do is to post a self-answer and accept that. That way others can see the question was answered, and the question becomes more useful for folks who are stuck in the same situation going forward.

Comment: When I tried your answer I still had the same problem. The new user uid in the Firebase database is different to one in the firebase authentication. What I did instead of adding user's information(uid,name and phone number) into my firebase database from the method called signInWithPhoneAuthCredential which is in VerifyAccount class. I passed user name and phone number from VerifyAccount class to Hobbies class. There in Hobbies class I have another button. When I press that button then the user information is added to the firebase. I don't add users information in the VerifyClass.

Comment: If that solved the problem, the best thing to do is to post a self-answer and accept that. That way others can see the question was answered, and the question becomes more useful for folks who are stuck in the same situation going forward.